# Postgresql index is not used for slow queries >30s

Tags: postgresql

POSTGRESQL VERSION: 10
HARDWARE: 4 workers / 16GBRAM / 50% used

I'm not a Postgresql expert. I have just read a lot of documentation and did a lot of tests.
I have some postgresql queries whick take a lot of times > 30s because of 10 millions of rows on a table.

```
            Column            |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                         Default                          
------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id                           | integer                  |           | not null | 
 cveid                        | character varying(50)    |           |          | 
 summary                      | text                     |           | not null | 
 published                    | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 modified                     | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 assigner                     | character varying(128)   |           |          | 
 vulnerable_products          | character varying(250)[] |           |          | 
 cvss                         | double precision         |           |          | 
 cvss_time                    | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 cvss_vector                  | character varying(250)   |           |          | 
 access                       | jsonb                    |           | not null | 
 impact                       | jsonb                    |           | not null | 
 score                        | integer                  |           | not null | 
 is_exploitable               | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 is_confirmed                 | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 is_in_the_news               | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 is_in_the_wild               | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 reflinks                     | jsonb                    |           | not null | 
 reflinkids                   | jsonb                    |           | not null | 
 created_at                   | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 history_id                   | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('vulns_historicalvuln_history_id_seq'::regclass)
 history_date                 | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 history_change_reason        | character varying(100)   |           |          | 
 history_type                 | character varying(1)     |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "vulns_historicalvuln_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (history_id)
    "btree_varchar" btree (history_type varchar_pattern_ops)
    "vulns_historicalvuln_cve_id_850876bb" btree (cve_id)
    "vulns_historicalvuln_cwe_id_2013d697" btree (cwe_id)
    "vulns_historicalvuln_history_user_id_9e25ebf5" btree (history_user_id)
    "vulns_historicalvuln_id_773f2af7" btree (id)
--- TRUNCATE
Foreign-key constraints:
    "vulns_historicalvuln_history_user_id_9e25ebf5_fk_custusers" FOREIGN KEY (history_user_id) REFERENCES custusers_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Example of queries:
SELECT * FROM vulns_historicalvuln WHERE history_type <> '+' order by id desc fetch first 10000 rows only; -> 30s without cache

**QUERY PLAN**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..31878.33 rows=10000 width=1736) (actual time=0.173..32839.474 rows=10000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using vulns_historicalvuln_id_773f2af7 on vulns_historicalvuln  (cost=0.43..26346955.92 rows=8264960 width=1736) (actual time=0.172..32830.958 rows=10000 loops=1)
         Filter: ((history_type)::text <> '+'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 296
 Planning time: 19.514 ms
 Execution time: 32845.015 ms
```

SELECT DISTINCT "vulns"."id", "vulns"."uuid", "vulns"."feedid", "vulns"."cve_id", "vulns"."cveid", "vulns"."summary", "vulns"."published", "vulns"."modified", "vulns"."assigner", "vulns"."cwe_id", "vulns"."vulnerable_packages_versions", "vulns"."vulnerable_products", "vulns"."vulnerable_product_versions", "vulns"."cvss", "vulns"."cvss_time", "vulns"."cvss_version", "vulns"."cvss_vector", "vulns"."cvss_metrics", "vulns"."access", "vulns"."impact", "vulns"."cvss3", "vulns"."cvss3_vector", "vulns"."cvss3_version", "vulns"."cvss3_metrics", "vulns"."score", "vulns"."is_exploitable", "vulns"."is_confirmed", "vulns"."is_in_the_news", "vulns"."is_in_the_wild", "vulns"."reflinks", "vulns"."reflinkids", "vulns"."created_at", "vulns"."updated_at", "vulns"."id" AS "exploit_count", false AS "monitored", '42' AS "org" FROM "vulns" WHERE ("vulns"."score" >= 0 AND "vulns"."score" <= 100) ORDER BY "vulns"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 10

---

**QUERY PLAN**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=315191.32..315192.17 rows=10 width=1691) (actual time=3013.964..3013.990 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=315191.32..329642.42 rows=170013 width=1691) (actual time=3013.962..3013.986 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=315191.32..315616.35 rows=170013 width=1691) (actual time=3013.961..3013.970 rows=10 loops=1)
               Sort Key: updated_at DESC, id, uuid, feedid, cve_id, cveid, summary, published, modified, assigner, cwe_id, vulnerable_packages_versions, vulnerable_products, vulnerable_product_versions, cvss, cvss_time, cvss_version, cvss_vector, cvss_metrics, access, impact, cvss3, cvss3_vector, cvss3_version, cvss3_metrics, score, is_exploitable, is_confirmed, is_in_the_news, is_in_the_wild, reflinks, reflinkids, created_at
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 277648kB
               ->  Seq Scan on vulns  (cost=0.00..50542.19 rows=170013 width=1691) (actual time=0.044..836.597 rows=169846 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((score >= 0) AND (score <= 100))
 Planning time: 3.183 ms
 Execution time: 3070.346 ms
```

I have created a btree varchar index `btree_varchar" btree (history_type varchar_pattern_ops)` like this:
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY btree_varchar ON vulns_historicalvuln (history_type varchar_pattern_ops);

I have also created a index for vulns score for my second queries:
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ON vulns (score);

I read a lot of post and documentation about slow queries and index. I'am sure it's the solution about slow queries but the query plan of Postgresql doesn't use the index I have created. It estimates that it processes faster with seq scan than using the index...

```
SELECT relname, indexrelname, idx_scan FROM   pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_indexes;

               relname               |                          indexrelname                           |  idx_scan  
-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 vulns_historicalvuln                | btree_varchar                                                   |          0
```

Could you tell me if my index is well designed ? How I can debug this, feel free to ask more information if needed.

Thanks

Comment: `history_type` is a **low-cardinality** column. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68306005/905902

Comment: The one that takes 30 seconds **is** using an index, and one not using an index takes much less than 30 seconds.

Comment: @wildplasser is right. Your filter is only removing 254 out of 10 million you said. This query is basically just sorting 10 million rows.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cardinality and database. I found this definition:
We usually don’t talk about cardinality as a number, though. It’s more common to simply talk about “high” and “low” cardinality. A lot of distinct values is high cardinality; a lot of repeated values is low cardinality.

Comment: Ok so 30s to query 10 millions rows is "usual". Index is not the solution here so I have to remake my postgres query or storage to make it faster ?
For example, history_type is a character which is:
* '+' -> creation
* '~' -> modification
* '-' -> suppression
Maybe there is a way to make it better like use an ENUM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I understand that index is not the solution of my problem here.
Low_cardinality (repeated value) of this field make the index useless.

The time of the query postgresql here is normal because of 30M rows matched.
I close this issue because there is no problem with index here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).